# One javascript for mutliple divs?

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML and a script

```js
/**
 * Increment value with random intervals.
 * @param {string} id - Id of DOM Element.
 * @param {number} start - Start counter value. Applied immediately.
 * @param {number} end - End counter value.
 * @duration {number} duration - Max duration of one iteration in ms.
 */
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
  let current = start;
  const obj = document.getElementById(id);
  obj.innerHTML = current; // immediately apply start value
  const setIncrOut = () => {
    let time = Math.random() * 500;
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (current < end) {
        current += 1;
        obj.innerHTML = current;
        setIncrOut(time)
      }
    }, time);
  }

  setIncrOut();
}

animateValue("value", 100, 1000000);
```

```html
<div id="value">100</div>
```

Basically I want to use this 1 script for multiple divs:

```
<div id="value2">100</div>
<div id="value3">100</div>
<div id="value4">100</div>
```

I know that div id must match the script id, is there a workaround, so that I wouldn't need to duplicate the same script and simply use just one?

I'm planning to use over 200 of them, so I thought it's not feasible and using just one will save a lot resources.

**EDIT:** I figured I can use:

```
animateValue("value", 100, 1000000);
animateValue("value2", 100, 1000000);
animateValue("value3", 100, 1000000);
```

But maybe there's even simpler solution?

Comment: Use a class? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Use a class and since you are using let, you can just call with the object

```js
/**
 * Increment value with random intervals.
 * @param {string} id - Id of DOM Element.
 * @param {number} start - Start counter value. Applied immediately.
 * @param {number} end - End counter value.
 * @duration {number} duration - Max duration of one iteration in ms.
 */
function animateValue(obj, start, end, duration) {
  let current = start;
  obj.innerHTML = current; // immediately apply start value
  const setIncrOut = () => {
    let time = Math.random() * 500;
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (current < end) {
        current += 1;
        obj.innerHTML = current;
        setIncrOut(time)
      }
    }, time);
  }
  setIncrOut();
}

document.querySelectorAll(".incr").forEach(obj => animateValue(obj, 100, 1000000));
```

```html
<div class="incr">100</div>
<div class="incr">100</div>
```